# Making a div expand to all the screen overlaying other divs

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay

I have a 2 by 2 grid of divs displaying each time I enter the page that fills the entire browser screen.

I want to make it in a way that if I hover over each of the divs that one will fullscreen expand over the other three, hiding them while those stay still.

What I have right now doesn't quite work because when I hover over one of the divs it moves all the other ones and ruins the screen. I would really appreciate any advice.

HTML (it's just this inside the body):

```
<div class="box" id="sup-izq"></div>
<div class="box" id="sup-der"></div>
<div class="box" id="inf-izq"></div>
<div class="box" id="inf-der"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#sup-izq {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #8cff66;
}

#sup-der {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ff751a;
}

#inf-izq {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #3385ff;
}

#inf-der {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #d147a3;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and most performant way to do that is to use [`transform: scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform?v=control) and [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin?v=control)

The `scale(2)` will double its size in both directions (width/height) and the `transform-origin`, which defaults to `center center` (50% 50%), controls the origin.

*Note, for an element to have a height set in precent, its parent need a height, hence I added the `html, body` rule. Another option would be to use [viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) `vw`/`vh`*

```css
html, body {                            /*  added rule  */
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s,          /*  changed property  */
              z-index 0.5s;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scale(2);                  /*  added property  */
  z-index: 10;                     /*  added so hovered is on top  */
}

#sup-izq {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #8cff66;
  transform-origin: left top;           /*  added property  */
}

#sup-der {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ff751a;
  transform-origin: right top;          /*  added property  */
}

#inf-izq {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #3385ff;
  transform-origin: left bottom;        /*  added property  */
}

#inf-der {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #d147a3;
  transform-origin: right bottom;       /*  added property  */
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="sup-izq"></div>
<div class="box" id="sup-der"></div>
<div class="box" id="inf-izq"></div>
<div class="box" id="inf-der"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's perfect. Could you please tell me why it's the most performant way to do this compared to mayersdesign way, for example?

Comment: @DokAsov Because `transform` make use of GPU hardware acceleration, which you can read more about here: [**Hardware Acceleration with CSS**](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-hardware-acceleration-css-animations/)

Answer (score 1):

This is rough and ready, but works. The approach was to wrap everything in a relatively positioned wrapper, then position the squares absolutely. That way they can have a z-index, which was the crux of the matter.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s;
  position: absolute;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#sup-izq {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #8cff66;
}

#sup-der {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ff751a;
}

#inf-izq {
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #3385ff;
}

#inf-der {
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #d147a3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box" id="sup-izq"></div>
  <div class="box" id="sup-der"></div>
  <div class="box" id="inf-izq"></div>
  <div class="box" id="inf-der"></div>
</div>
```